# Trying to convert this big if else statement into a loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, for-loop

Hi I'm trying to make this code more clean. I struggle with arrays and loops and have no idea how to convert this into into a loop. This is javascript for a form on an html page and if they leave a field blank, when they hit submit it should return an alert box and if everything is submitted properly it should confirm with them. There's also a reg exp for an acceptable postal code entry.

```
function validate() 
{
    var register = document.forms[0];
    if (register.fname.value === "") 
{
    alert("Please fill out your first name.");
    return false;
}
    else if(register.lname.value === "") 
{
    alert("Please fill out your last name.");
    return false;
}
    else if(register.address.value === "") 
{
    alert("Please fill out your address.");
    return false;
}
    else if(register.postal.value ==="")
{
    alert("Please enter a valid postal code.");
    return false;
}
    else if(!checkPostal(register.postal.value))
{
    alert("Please enter a valid postal code.");
    return false;
}
    else if(register.eAddress.value === "") 
{
    alert("Please fill out your email address.");
    return false;
}
    return confirm("Is the information correct?");
}


 //postal code regExp
 function checkPostal() 
{
    var myReg =  /^[A-Z]\d[A-Z] ?\d[A-Z]\d$/ig;
    return myReg.test(document.getElementById("postal").value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this a pure HTML solution if you want to reduce javascript:

inputs have a `required` attr <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required)</sup>

additionally, inputs have a `pattern` attr <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#htmlattrdefpattern)</sup> that supports regex.

This kind of solution lets the browser handle feedback

```html
<form>
  <label>first name: 
    <input type="text" name="fname" required
       minlength="1">
  </label><br/>
  <label>last name: 
    <input type="text" name="lname" required
       minlength="1">
  </label><br/>
  <label>postal code: 
    <input type="text" name="zip" required pattern="^[A-Z]\d[A-Z] ?\d[A-Z]\d$"
       minlength="1">
  </label><br/>

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$.each( $( "#input input" ), function( key, element ) {
  if( !$(element).val() ) {
    $( "#error" + key ).text( "Input " + $( element ).attr( "name" ) + " is required");
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your message as attribute on each element of the form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="submit.php">
    <input id="item1" type="text" value="" data-message="My error message" data-must="true">
    ...//do the same for other elements...
</form>
```

Now loop like below

```
var elements = document.forms[0].elements;

for (var i = 0, element; element = elements[i++];) {
    if (element.getAttribute("must") && element.value === ""){
        alert(element.getAttribute("message"));
        return false;
    }
} 
return confirm("Is the information correct?");
```